# Validation in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I having a textbox which user need to enter customer number(ex : 123456789).
    what is my issue is if they enter (ex:000000000 or 000 or,0000,or 00000) I need to valid as it is ID Should not be zero invalid . how I need to do in C# code behind .

Comment: you can check the textbox value and make sure it is different from 0

Comment: Why don't you simply check `value>0` ??

Answer (score 1):

> I need to valid as it is ID Should not be zero invalid

If this is the only rule (I can't say like it), you can try to parse your `string` (which is probably you get this from user) with [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.TryParse.aspx) method and then check your integer is bigger than `0` or not. Like;

```
string input;
int number;
if (Int32.TryParse(input, out number))
{
   if(number > 0)
   {
       // Your input can be parsed to int and it is greater than zero.
   }        
}
```

Remember, don't check your number is `0` or not. Because if your string couldn't parse with `Int32.TryParse` method, your number will be `0` by default.

> result Type:
>   System.Int32
>
> When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value
>   equivalent of the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded,
>   **or zero if the conversion failed**.

Comment: Not sure where the `int i` came from. Edited anyway :P

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Me neither :) Thanks.